# How do you use a rewrite rule to send certain page requests to Zend MVC application?

Tags: model-view-controller, wordpress, zend-framework, .htaccess, redirect

I need a certain set of URLS to go to a Zend/MVC

```
/races/super-star
/races/race-57
/races/space-ace
```

and another set of URLS to go to WordPress

```
/
/home.php
/staff/bios.php
/company/about.php
```

The problem is that wordpress is in

```
/apps/wordpress
```

I can't figure out how to do this with htaccess redirects

> RewriteRule ^app/wordpress(/?)(.*)$ /$2
>   [NC,R=301,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

RewriteRule ^/$ /apps/wordpress/?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+).php$ /apps/wordpress/?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+).php$ /apps/wordpress/?page=$1 [L]

the first line is for the /
the second line is for /home.php
the third line is for all urls in the form /staff/bios.php etc

and as far as your zend urls they don't need any rules.